# How to fix the width of bar in waterfall chart as well as its x-axis width of one group.?

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWwOs.jpg)

I am trying to set fixed width for bars in the waterfall chart using pointWidth but using that I am unable to increase width of entire group of bars.

I tried it using groupPadding and pointPadding. It didnt help much.

Below is the chartoptions I have used to set in highcharts.

```
{
    chart: {
      type: "waterfall"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Grouped Waterfall"
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories:['Commission', 'Client Fee', 'Fee', 'Discount', 'Payaway', 'Revenue'],
      crosshair: true
    },

    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'GWP'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      waterfall: {
        pointWidth: 20,
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Tokyo",
        data: [
          { y: 116440000, w: 20 }, 
          { y: 9390000, w: 20 }, 
          { y: 5410000, w: 20 }, 
          { y: -66880000, w: 20 }, 
          { y: -2270000, w: 20 }, 
          { y: 62090000, isSum: true }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "New York",
        data: [
          { y: 9390000 }, 
          { y: 116440000 }, 
          {  y: -66880000 }, 
          { y: 5410000 }, 
          { y: -2270000 }, 
          { isSum: true, y: 62090000 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "London",
        data: [
          { y: 116440000 }, 
          { y: 9390000 }, 
          { y: 5410000 }, 
          { y: -66880000 }, 
          { y: -2270000 }, 
          { isSum: true, y: 62090000 }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Mayuri Rathod, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve? The `pointWidth` option seems to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L4oq5gzf/

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi, I want to increase the width of 3 columns together that is width of **commission** or **Client Fee**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pointWidth` option for a individual data point:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{
        y: 116440000,
        pointWidth: 20
    }, ... ]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c0yxh432/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.pointWidth

Comment: This will add overlap on the bar, which I dont want.

Comment: @Mayuri Rathod, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n2td5u18/

Comment: I have added image in the question. If you will have look at that, then you will be the change in bar and table under commission. Here, with increase in number of bars, bar width is constant, space between them is constant. And the table aligns itself below it with that lengths being specific.    But as of now, I dont have control over the width entirely. It would be great if you can help me resolve this problem statement

Comment: Hi @Mayuri Rathod, So I understand that you want all columns to be the same width? For example, would you like all columns to be the same width on these charts (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eb872k1r/)?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Yes, While I also want to control that width using chartOptions

Comment: Hi @Mayuri Rathod, To achieve the wanted result you need to use some custom calculation. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/frk0hxsq/